# Unsupported compiler 'org.llvm.8.1.1.clang.wrapper' selected for architecture 'x86_64'Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for file

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

When I was working on a test, I connected my cellphone(iphone 5s) and my mac, and then I found that Xcode reported an error. Anyone who had solved this problem? Could you help me?

> Unsupported compiler 'org.llvm.8.1.1.clang.wrapper' selected for
>   architecture 'x86_64' Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for
>   file
>   /Users/dandy.guan/Desktop/fordPass/ford-oa-ios/Externals/Powertrain/Powertrain/Guardspec/action_powertrain.c
>   of type sourcecode.c.c. Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for
>   file
>   /Users/dandy.guan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fordowner-faaziajnofjrgcdylfksmsfuyxzk/Build/Intermediates/Powertrain.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/action_powertrain.build/DerivedSources/action_powertrain_vers.c
>   of type sourcecode.c.c.

Comment: Not sure, but you can give a try by deleting derived data of Xcode.

Comment: Thank you. I had solved this problem. But I didn't know the reason. I found an answer that someone said that,  'Just restart your computer, I don't know why the problem was disappear!'  :-)